# What does this regexp match on? /([^"^\s]+)\s*|"([^"]+)"\s*/g

Tags: regex, alfresco

I should really be able to read a regexp by now, but all the same can anyone talk me through this?

```
/([^"^\s]+)\s*|"([^"]+)"\s*/g
```

Just for background; it's used in Alfresco to match on document tags. Is there a website out there you can plug these into and get an explanation back (other than SO)!

Comment: While it's true that this question won't be useful to visitors, it's because they'd be unable to search for it; the regex is really useful for a lot of applications (especially if you improve it by adding quote escapes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It either matches an identifier (something that doesn't contain `"`, `^`, or any space-like character -- space, tab, new lines) or something between quotes, either followed by any number of spaces.

Answer (score 6):

```
(        # start a capture group
[^"^\s]+ # one or more characters NOT quote, caret, or white space
)        # close capture group
\s*      # followed by optional white space
|  # either match everything before this '|' or everything after it
"        # match a quote character
(        # start capture group
[^"]+    # one or more characters NOT quote
)        # close capture group
"        # the closing quote
\s*      # followed by optional white space
```

So as Blindy said, it either matches a string that doesn't have '^', quotes, or whitespace,  OR, it matches everything between two quote characters. And it saves what it found in a backreference (what I've called 'groups' because I have Python stuck in my head).

Comment: It's funny how regex brings developers closer together, I have the C# version stuck in my head!

Comment: The Regex Suite in C# Minor, I presume? :)

Comment: The one thing I can sing without sounding off-key!